# Can't turn off network

Tags: networking

I'm trying to set up cron to turn off networking on my Raspberry Pi during the night (from 23:00 to 8:00).

The problem is that none of this commands do the job:

```
$ sudo service networking stop
$ sudo ifconfig eth0 down
$ sudo ifdown eth0
```

From the output it looks like the command worked but the interface is still up (I can ping 8.8.8.8 and it's present in ifconfig).

This is the content of /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

auto wlan1
allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

output of ifconfig (masked MAC)

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  
          inet addr:192.168.1.102  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1545 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1054 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:117138 (114.3 KiB)  TX bytes:156391 (152.7 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1104 (1.0 KiB)  TX bytes:1104 (1.0 KiB)
```

output of route -n

```
Kernel IP routing table

Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 eth0
```

The outputs of ifconfig and route -n are the same before and after the 3 commands

Any help?

Comment: Try adding `service ifplugd stop` as well.

Comment: @goldilocks still not working

Comment: And you are sure those commands are actually being executed?  I would put them in a script together, piping output to a file, as well as logging `$?` (status of last command).  Note that stuff run by the system cron shouldn't use `sudo`, it is run root anyway.

Comment: @goldilocks Have a look: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lpb5dkyaccq6xir/file%2022-07-15%2016%2053%2034.jpeg?dl=0

Comment: Since you aren't using wlan0 and wlan1 can you comment those stanzas 4 lines each and then try again?

Comment: o_O That's screwed up.  Try stopping `ifplugd` **first**, make sure it is gone with `ps -A | grep ifplug`, then `ifconfig eth0 down`.  Are you using DHCP?

Comment: @goldilocks it outputs "Sorry, there is already an instance of ifplugd for eth0 running." I do use DHCP on my modem/router and i have the ip of the pi reserved by the router

Comment: @goldilocks running ps -A ... I see 2 processes of ifplugd

Comment: @goldilocks I rebooted the pi, it seems to work now since i've lost ssh connection. Thank you very much

Comment: If you just want to stop outbound you could change the DNS or Gateway IP to a random, non existent IP. That will "stop" internet from working.

Comment: @ppumkin changing DNS prevents translation of names to IPs, but would not block outbound access from any app using an IP address or that may have cached the result of a DNS lookup.   Changing the gateway IP would block outbound _and_ inbound traffic, because you need to route packets back to the sender in order to complete a connection.   Since the OP is happy to have his network completely down, that would be one way to accomplish it.

Comment: Yea, I suppose. But not really sure whats going on here. I think installing a firewall would work better. does `pf` work on Raspian yet?

Answer (score -1):

What about:

> /etc/init.d/networking stop

Comment: I get "[...] deconfiguring network interfaces" but nothing changes, still on

Comment: What you've written is basically same as service networking stop